# I cannot detect the error. Why 3rd and 4th (else if )are not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I cannot detect the error that i made below . Why 3rd and 4th (else if )are nor working. Can you detect the error ?

```
       var x = prompt ("Hey , Who are you ? Put Your name below ");
        if (x === "najmul"){
            alert ("Hey, Young Man. How was the journey?");
        }

        else if (x === "mahmud" || "mona"){
            alert ("hum, I saw you with Najmul!");
        }

        else if (x === "sabbir"){
            alert ("Further options are not enabled for under 18");
        }

        else if (x === "Abbas"){
            alert ("Hola Abbas");
        }
        else {
            alert ("Do I know You?");

        }
```

Comment: Replace `else if (x === "mahmud" || "mona"){` with `else if (x === "mahmud" || x === "mona"){`

Comment: If you want a short condition, it could be `else if(["mahmud", "mona"].indexOf(x) + 1)`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
else if (x === "mahmud" || "mona"){
```

with

```
else if (x === "mahmud" || x === "mona"){
```

Comment: No, idea. It's the exact same answer as one given above.

Comment: Same as @vaxo, yes, because that's the solution. Same as the comment, yes, it's the same person. Don't understand why the 2 answers were immediately downvoted. Bizarre.

Answer (score 1):

becose, `if (x === "mahmud" || "mona")` always is `true`.

try `if (x === "mahmud" || x === "mona")`

Answer (score 0):

This condition:

```
x === "mahmud" || "mona"
```

will always be : `x === "mahmud"`, since it is how it is parsed.

Use :

```
else if (x === "mahmud" || x === "mona")
```

So, it always evaluates to `true`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare a value with two values you have to check with individually like

```
x == "mahmud" || x == "mona"
```

Answer (score -1):

Your 2nd condition is always true. This is the correct code:

```
   var x = prompt ("Hey , Who are you ? Put Your name below ");
    if (x === "najmul"){
        alert ("Hey, Young Man. How was the journey?");
    }

    else if (x === "mahmud" || x === "mona"){
        alert ("hum, I saw you with Najmul!");
    }

    else if (x === "sabbir"){
        alert ("Further options are not enabled for under 18");
    }

    else if (x === "Abbas"){
        alert ("Hola Abbas");
    }
    else {
        alert ("Do I know You?");

    }
```